Terraform + Github Workflow
I am using EC2 instances for hosting my nodejs web application which is in a private github repo. I want to make this autoscaling so I moved user_data script to a aws_launch_configuration.
My question is how can I create a CICD Pipeline(Github Workflows) to deploy my code latest code to EC2 when I pushed to branch.
And I want to pull the latest code to the EC2 when it is autoscaling.
My Current TF
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "awslc" {
  name_prefix     = "asg-"
  image_id        = "ami-09e647bf7a368e505"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  user_data       = file("user-data.sh")
  security_groups = []

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

I have a private repo, how can I pull the latest code for this?
# Clone website code
echo "Cloning website"
mkdir -p /demo-website
cd /demo-website
git clone https://github.com/test.git . ????

I dont want to use PAT(Personal Access Tokens), what alternates I have here?
Thanks

What have you tried already? Have you read the documentation?

@MarkoE Yeah. I dont have idea on how can do both at once 1. On Git Push, 2. When ASG spin up

Instead of pushing the latest code to the running instances, I would trigger your AutoScaling group to replace your existing instances with new ones. When the new ones spin up they will pull the newest code.  You can do this by triggering an Instance Refresh from your GitHub pipeline https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-instance-refresh.html

Probably the only secure alternative to a PAT here would be an IAM instance profile. Other options would be less secure than either of those two.
